# SQL Query: Employee Database

Tags: sql

I have such SQL Database  where there are employees and supervisors assigned to them. For supervisors who have no male employees working for them, I need to find the SSN and the total number of employees working for them.

This is how my table in database looks: [image]

And here is my code for the solution:

```
SELECT supervisors.ssn, COUNT(e.ssn)
FROM employee AS supervisors, employee AS e
WHERE e.ssn NOT IN (SELECT e.ssn FROM employee e WHERE e.sex = 'M') AND supervisors.ssn = e.superssn
GROUP BY supervisors.ssn;
```

But the code above finds the supervisors who has at least one Female employee. However, I need to find supervisors who have **only** Female employees.

Comment: mysql or sql server? They are NOT the same thing. Pretty sure from the syntax this is sql server. You should also use an explicit join. They have been part of the standard now for nearly 30 years. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many of the Answers will exclude results if the Supervisor is Male

This will not

```
SELECT employee.lname, count(employee.lname) as NumberOfEmployees 
FROM Employee
INNER JOIN (

SELECT Employee.SuperSSN
FROM Employee
WHERE Employee.SuperSSN NOT IN
(SELECT Employee.SuperSSN FROM Employee e
INNER JOIN Employee
ON e.SSN = Employee.SuperSSN
WHERE Employee.SEX = 'M')
)
AS e
ON Employee.ssn = e.superssn
GROUP BY employee.lname
```

Comment: Thank you! Would be great if you explain your answer, please

Comment: By parts: Inner most query: `SELECT Employee.SuperSSN FROM Employee e
INNER JOIN Employee
ON e.SSN = Employee.SuperSSN
WHERE Employee.SEX = 'M'`  This returns the supervisors that have at least 1 male working for them. The total inner query `SELECT Employee.SuperSSN
FROM Employee
WHERE Employee.SuperSSN NOT IN
(SELECT Employee.SuperSSN ....` returns the superSSN of employees with a supervisor where the supervisor doesn't have any male workers. You must join to this entire query to get the supervisors' name(s) and count of the employees under them

Comment: My answer does not exclude results if the supervisor is male

Comment: You are right, but it will return a supervisor if they have at least one female working under them (but not all females). The asker wants supervisors with no Males working for them

Answer (score 1):

You have a query that returns all the supervisors who have at least one female employee.

If you change the way you think about what you want, it's easy to get your results.

You want a query that returns all supervisors who are NOT a member of the set of supervisors who have at least one male employee.

Answer (score 0):

something like this ?

```
SELECT supervisors.ssn
FROM   employee AS supervisors
  inner join employee e on supervisors.ssn = e.supersnn
                       and e.sex = 'F'
group by supervisors.ssn
```